# lightbox images not centering

Tags: html, css, image, lightbox

I have an issue with my lightbox images not centering. The images are not centering to the page and centering to the column that they are in. I cannot see where I can get this to center as it looks to be correct. I would appreciate anyone's help.

The website is http://temp1.absolutehtml.co.uk/gallery.html

HTML

```
<a class="lightbox" href="#image1">
   <img src="../images/pexels-photo (1).jpg" alt="image1"/>
</a> 
                  <!-- lightbox -->
<div class="lightbox-target" id="image1">
   <img src="../images/pexels-photo (1).jpg" alt="image1"/>
   <a class="lightbox-close" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Styles the lightbox, removes it from sight and adds the fade-in transition */

.lightbox-target {
position: fixed;
top: -100%;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* Styles the lightbox image, centers it vertically and horizontally, adds the zoom-in transition and makes it responsive using a combination of margin and absolute positioning */

.lightbox-target img {
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom: 0;
max-height: 0%;
max-width: 0%;
border: 3px solid white;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Styles the close link, adds the slide down transition */

a.lightbox-close {
display: block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: white;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
top: -80px;
right: 0;
-webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */

a.lightbox-close:before {
content: "";
display: block;
height: 30px;
width: 1px;
background: black;
position: absolute;
left: 26px;
top:10px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
-o-transform:rotate(45deg);
transform:rotate(45deg);
}

/* Provides part of the "X" to eliminate an image from the close link */

a.lightbox-close:after {
content: "";
display: block;
height: 30px;
width: 1px;
background: black;
position: absolute;
left: 26px;
top:10px;
-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

/* Uses the :target pseudo-class to perform the animations upon clicking the .lightbox-target anchor */

.lightbox-target:target {
opacity: 1;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
}

.lightbox-target:target img {
margin-top: 4%;
max-height: 90%;
max-width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

.lightbox-target:target a.lightbox-close {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-right: 6%;
top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image *is* centered within its container, but the container goes off the screen. You set it to `position: fixed` and `width: 100%`, which makes it as wide as the viewport. But you don't set `left` or `right`, so its horizontal position is just wherever that element would naturally appear.

Adding this will fix your problem:

```
.lightbox-target {
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Any idea whats going on here? Its fine on desktop but on a smaller device, the image is displayed too high.

https://ibb.co/g5eqzc

Answer (score 0):

Add this to styles:

> .ril-image-current { max-width: none !important; }